# Apply changes consecutively in a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with an initial status named init. I have a dataframe with the same schema where it has updates for one field of dataframe init per row and Null in other fields. How can I reconstruct each record applying the changes consecutively? To be more clear lets have this example:

```py
listOfTuples = [(101, "Status_0", '2019','value_col_4',0)]
init = spark.createDataFrame(listOfTuples , ["id", "status", "year","col_4","ord"])

#initial state
>>> init.show()
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
| id|  status|year|      col_4|ord|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
|  1|Status_0|2019|value_col_4|  0|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+

#dataframe with changes
schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('status', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('year', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('col_4', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('ord', IntegerType(), True)])

listOfTuples = [(1, "Status_A", None, None,1),
                (1, "Status_B", None, None,2),
                (1, None, None, "new_val", 3),
                (1, "Status_C", None, None,4)]


changes = spark.createDataFrame(listOfTuples ,  schema)
>>> changes.show()
+---+--------+----+-------+---+
| id|  status|year|  col_4|ord|
+---+--------+----+-------+---+
|  1|Status_A|null|   null|  1|
|  1|Status_B|null|   null|  2|
|  1|    null|null|new_val|  3|
|  1|Status_C|null|   null|  4|
+---+--------+----+-------+---+
```

I want the changes to be applied in final dataframe consecutively with the order of ord column and baseline the values in dataframe init. So I want my final dataframe to be like:

```
>>> final.show()
+---+--------+----+--------------+
| id|  status|year|  col_4       |
+---+--------+----+--------------+
|  1|Status_0|2019|  value_col_4 |
|  1|Status_A|2019|  value_col_4 |
|  1|Status_B|2019|  value_col_4 |
|  1|Status_B|2019|  new_val     |
|  1|Status_C|2019|  new_val     |
+---+--------+----+--------------+
```

I was thinking about unioning the two dataframes sort by ord column and then propagate changes somehow below. Has anyone any idea how to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to do it using a window function, so partition by `id`, sort by `ord`, then for every column do a `coalesce` with the previous row. I'm not sure if that'll work though.

Comment: I need to take the value of previous row only if curent row has no update value (null column) - I am not sure how exacrtly this will work with coalesce.

Comment: `coalesce` takes 2 arguments. If the first is null it returns the second. So say you do `df.withColumn(c, F.coalesce(F.col(c), F.lag(c).over(win))` that'll replace the previous row's values with the update if there is a change. The only thing I'm not sure about is whether the updates are cumulative or will you just be getting null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Scala code, but I hope this helps. You may drop or rename the columns in the end.
Solution is to do a `union` and then get the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.last` not null value with in a frame of `unboundedpreceding` rows to `currentrow` for all the 3 columns.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> initial.show
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
| id|  status|year|      col_4|ord|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
|  1|Status_0|2019|value_col_4|  0|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+

scala> changes.show
+---+--------+----+-------+---+
| id|  status|year|  col_4|ord|
+---+--------+----+-------+---+
|  1|Status_A|null|   null|  1|
|  1|Status_B|null|   null|  2|
|  1|    null|null|new_val|  3|
|  1|Status_C|null|   null|  4|
+---+--------+----+-------+---+


scala> val inter = initial.union(changes)
inter: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: string, status: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> inter.show
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
| id|  status|year|      col_4|ord|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+
|  1|Status_0|2019|value_col_4|  0|
|  1|Status_A|null|       null|  1|
|  1|Status_B|null|       null|  2|
|  1|    null|null|    new_val|  3|
|  1|Status_C|null|       null|  4|
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+


scala> val overColumns = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("ord").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@70f4b378

scala> val output = inter.withColumn("newstatus", 
  last("status", true).over(overColumns)).withColumn("newyear",
  last("year", true).over(overColumns)).withColumn("newcol_4", 
  last("col_4", true).over(overColumns))
output: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, status: string ... 6 more fields]

scala> output.show(false)
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+---------+-------+-----------+
|id |status  |year|col_4      |ord|newstatus|newyear|newcol_4   |
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+---------+-------+-----------+
|1  |Status_0|2019|value_col_4|0  |Status_0 |2019   |value_col_4|
|1  |Status_A|null|null       |1  |Status_A |2019   |value_col_4|
|1  |Status_B|null|null       |2  |Status_B |2019   |value_col_4|
|1  |null    |null|new_val    |3  |Status_B |2019   |new_val    |
|1  |Status_C|null|null       |4  |Status_C |2019   |new_val    |
+---+--------+----+-----------+---+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In python using the code from  @C.S.Reddy Gadipally

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

f = init.union(changes)

w = Window.partitionBy(f['id']).orderBy(f['ord'])

for c in f.columns[1:]:
    f = f.withColumn(c,func.last(c,True).over(w))
```